# How can I get the current height of a QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, pyqt5, qlabel

In here, the label is cut and the `imageLabel` picture of the cat has the value of x = 0 and y = the height of the label.

[image: The label is Cut]

```py
layout = QVBoxLayout()

widget = QWidget()

label = QLabel("Lourim Ipsum ...", parent=widget) # LONG TEXT
label.setWordWard(True)

image = QPixmap("cat.png")
imageLabel = QLabel(parent=widget)
imageLabel.setPixmap(image)
imageLabel.setGeometry(0, label.height(), image.width(), image.height())

layout.addWidget(widget)
```

> **UPDATE:**

I have fixed the problem by doing some maths after `setWordWrap` Just like this

```py
layout = QVBoxLayout()

widget = QWidget()

label = QLabel("Lourim Ipsum ...", parent=widget) # LONG TEXT
label.setWordWard(True)
labe.adjustSize() # THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE

image = QPixmap("cat.png")
imageLabel = QLabel(parent=widget)
imageLabel.setPixmap(image)
```

> Set a constant width as 761 since its the layout's default width and set the height to this

```
dec = image.width()/761
wid = round(image.width()/dec) # Which will be 761.0 rounded to 761
hei = round(image.height()/dec)
imageLabel.setGeometry(0, label.height(), wid, hei)
imageLabel.adjustSize()

layout.addWidget(widget)
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word-wrapping must be set correctly on the top label, and both labels must be added to the layout. The layout must also be set on the container widget. It is not necessary to set the geometry of the labels, because the layout will do that automatically.

**UPDATE**:

There is a [problem with layouts that contain labels with word-wrapping](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues). It seems the height calculation can be wrong sometimes, which means the widgets may overlap.

Below is a demo that fixes these issues:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

TITLE = 'Cat for sale: Mint condition, still in original packaging'

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(TITLE)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        image = QtGui.QPixmap('cat.png')
        self.imageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(image)
        self.imageLabel.setFixedSize(image.size() + QtCore.QSize(0, 10))
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)
        layout.addStretch()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        height = self.label.height() + self.imageLabel.height()
        height += self.layout().spacing()
        margins = self.layout().contentsMargins()
        height += margins.top() + margins.bottom()
        if self.height() < height:
            self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        elif height < self.minimumHeight():
            self.setMinimumHeight(1)

widget= Widget()
widget.setStyleSheet('''
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    font-size: 26pt;
    ''')
widget.setWindowTitle('Test')
widget.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Since there is a part of your answer actually solved it which is the setStyleSheet, making font-size 16pt was kind of a solution, since the thing Im trying to accomplish does not need 3 lines and with 16pt font size it will never reach the 3 lines, but still does not solve the main problem which is making the image directly under the label and does not overlap with it.

Comment: @AoofXD I have updated my answer with a new solution which should solve the problem. Please try it out and confirm that it does what you want.